# Birefringent materials and Maxwell equation

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, birefringence

Maxwell's equations define the speed of light in a given medium at a given point through the equation:
$$\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t^2}=\mu\epsilon\nabla^2E$$

so according to it, the speed of light in a given medium should be constant in all directions. Then why do birefringent materials, which have different speed of light in different directions, even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In anisotropic materials there is a permittivity tensor instead of just a scalar.

Then the wave equation is

$$
\nabla^2 \vec{E} = -\omega^2 \mu_0 \vec{D}
$$

With
$$
\vec D = \bar \epsilon \vec E
$$
where $\bar \epsilon$ is a (rank 2) tensor, c.f.

https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ece303/Lectures/Lectures.htm, Lecture 17